# issue using mouseover event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using google map circle example and I want that there should appear an alert box whenever user hovers at the circled city.
Here is the code-

```
<script> 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var citymap = {
    chicago: {
      center: {lat: 41.878, lng: -87.629},
      population: 2714856
    }, 
  };
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {lat: 37.090, lng: -95.712},
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

    for (var city in citymap) {
      var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
      });
    }
  }
  var cityCircle= $('#mydiv');
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#mydiv').mouseover(function(){
      alert("welcome to chicago");
    });
 });
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

however circle is there but alert box is not appearing when I mouseover the city.
please guide me where I am wrong!
Thanks.

Comment: Where is "mydiv" in your HTML?

Comment: I set the id "mydiv" to citycircle in jquery. will it not work?

Comment: It is not magically going to rebind when you change the variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id is set to "mydiv" in the mouseover function, but your div is named "map"

EDIT :

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle,'mouseover',function()
            {alert("welcome to chicago"); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After you define circle in for loop

```
 cityCircle.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    alert("welcome to chicaho");
  });
```